# How to draw the direction field of van der pol oscillator?

Tags: matlab, field, ode

I am trying to get the direction field and phase portrait shown on this wiki page:

[Van der Pol oscillator in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator)

My code:

```
options = odeset('MaxStep',0.5);
temp = inputdlg('Enter mu value');
mu = str2double(temp{1,1});
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) vdp1_1(t,y,mu),[0 10],[2; 0],options);
plot(y(:,1),y(:,2));
hold on
quiver(y(:,1), y(:,2), gradient(y(:,1)), gradient(y(:,2) ))
hold off

function dydt = vdp1_1(t,y,mu)
    dydt = zeros(2,1);
    dydt(1) = y(2);
    dydt(2) = [mu * (1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)];
end
```

Current output:
[image: Actual output]

Desired Output:
How to get the direction field on top of this as shown in the wiki page figure

[image: Desired output]

Thanks,
Gopi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the vector field at every point you want an arrow to be shown. And then you plot this with quiver. For example.

```
[Xs,Ys]=meshgrid(-5:5,-5:5); % Will define the positions where we want to plot

Us=Ys; % From your equations, these are the values of the field at each point
Vs=mu*(1-Xs.^2).*Ys-Xs;

quiver(Xs,Ys,Us,Vs) % Should plot the field you want, just add the trajectory on top
```

Comment: Thanks it works great, But one doubt the arrows of the direction field near the path in curve is very small and not clear if not zoomed in, is their anyway to give size to this arrows in quiver plot to make them look big

Comment: Glad I could help. `quiver` scales proportionally the arrows to the grid they are drawn, so they don't overlap, you can change this value with the `scale` argument `quiver(x,y,u,v,scale)`. You can read more formatting options in the quiver documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html

Comment: Thanks, scale helps to adjust the arrows