# dsolve MATLAB :Explicit solution could not be found

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, dsolve

I want to solve the differential equation. MATLAB shows warning:

```
clear all
syms x f(x) theta 
eq = (-6*x+(-7+theta)*f*diff(f,x))*(1+diff(f,x)^2)+x*f*(diff(f,x,x))==0
cond = f(0)==1
dsolve(eq,cond)
```

---

```
 Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
> In dsolve (line 201)
  In dsolvef (line 5) 

ans =

[ empty sym ]
```

Is there a way to solve it?(analytically or numerically)
Thank you

Comment: Don't delete and reask the same questions. Your previous question → https://stackoverflow.com/q/46720078/

Answer (score 0):

There is a very high probability that no symbolic solution exists. In general the set of ODE that have symbolic solutions is "thin" in that slight variations of a symbolically solvable ODE make it unsolvable.

For a numerical solution use the `ode45` solver or implicit solvers like `ode15`. The all need an ODE function that encodes the ODE as explicit order 1 system.

```
function dz = derivs(x,z)
    y=z(1); dy = z(2)
    ddy = -(-6*x+(-7+theta)*y*dy)*(1+dy^2) / (x*y)
    dz = [ dy  ddy ]
 end
```

See also similar topics:

- [How do you plot nonlinear differential equations in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16023579/3088138)
- [How to draw the direction field of van der pol oscillator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42969046/3088138)